# Black lines in Smoke render

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Hello I'am new to blender, and I'am creating a ink drop in water animation using quick smoke simulation cycles render then after I finished rendering there's a strange black parts in the animation.

I would like to ask how can I remove these parts.

[image]

The attached link is the animation I rendered and the blend file.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/unismmxg1w31y3v/AAD24U5jXFh5umXuNgczPao8a?dl=0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 2.80 version (or 2.79 daily build) there is no this behavior:

[image]

And by the way, try this setting in color ramp, in my opinion, it produce more cooler ink-drop look.

Maybe this is a bug, and it was fixed in new version...

in 2.79b adding a little bit tint of color also helps:

[image]

Comment: Than you so much in suggestion and answer!
It works as you said.